# How to determine if a Point is within a certain distance of a line segment on a graph?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, computational-geometry

What I know:

There is a line segment from A to B. There is a third point C. I know...

- Point As (x,y) values
- Point Bs (x,y) values
- Point Cs (x,y,) values

I can figure out if C is on the line segment. This is achievable by determining if the "Distance from A to B" === ("Distance from A to C" + "Distance from C to B")

---

**However I want to be able to find out if Point C is "close" to the line segment, just not just "on the line segment" so it has room for "padding." i.e. "within n-number of points"**

I figured the best way to do this is to construct a rectangle around the line segment, equal distance above and below. Then calculate if Point C is within the rectangle.

[image: min]

So you would:

1. Construct a rectangle given two points on a line segment with a value for the padding above and below the line segment
2. Check if Point C is within the rectangle - which will likely be rotated on the graph.

**But how would you do each of these? especially considering the rectangle would be rotated? would you need to know the angle or rotation?**

Answer (score 1):

Convenient recipe would be to express point $C$ location in coordinates tied to your line segment. That is how far along $AB$ direction and how far off the $AB$ line.

You can achieve this by projecting $AC$ vector onto $(AB,\perp AB)$ basis. First compute $C-A$ to get $v = (c_x - a_x, c_y - a_y)$. Then find the components along each axis using dot product by

$along = (v . e_1) / |e_1|$

$across = (v . e_2) / |e_2|$

Where $e_1 = (b_x - a_x, b_y - a_y)$ and $e_2 = (-b_y + a_y, b_x - a_x)$

Working like this you can conveniently express you problem with inequalities such as $along < |AB|$.

[Wiki: dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do it without the linear algebra you could first write the equation for a line that passes through point C which is perpendicular to the line AB and then find that line's intersection point with the line AB. This gives you the closest point on the line AB to the point C. Then use the distance formula between them (√dx^2+dy^2) to get the distance.

To spare you from all of the algebraic equation solving the final result is:

D = |m(x_2 - x_1) - (y_2 - y_1)| / √(1+m^2)

Where (x_1, y_1) is point A, (x_2, y_2) is point C, and m is the slope from point A to point B (∆y/∆x or B.y - A.y / B.x - A.x).

In code you can just store 1/√(1+m^2) as a constant to multiply it with each time.

Another method. You can use the point's y distance to the line to create a right triangle with the line where the hypotenuse is that y distance. The angle of the line to the x axis would be atan(m) because tan is opp/adj and for the angle to the x axis opp would be rise and adj would be run. So ∆y/∆x or m. We need to find angle C of the right triangle which is the angle at point C between the line perpendicular to the original line and the y axis (because we calculate vertical y distance). Through some basic angle rules this angle is actually just the same one earlier of atan(m). The cosine of this angle would be the distance to the line (the adjacent side of angle C) over the hypotenuse (∆y). Rearrange and you get D = ∆y•cos(atan(m)). cos(atan(m)). Simplifies to 1/√(1+m^2) (look familiar?) so it is D= ∆y / √(1+m^2)

You can verify that the second solution yields the first because ∆y would be y_2 - f(x_2) and f(x) is the point slope equation f(x) = m(x - x_1) + y_1 so if you substitute that in it yields the first solution.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.